# android studio merging resource sets

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-resources

I have a project with multiple flavours. All resources are defined in src/main and some are overriden in /src/[flavour_name]. This has been working just fine.

However I now need to customize the flavours so that they belong to either one of two (or more, in the future) different client groups. I need the resources to be merged in this way (where --> signifies 'is overridden by'):

main source set-->client group-->flavour

I have tried using sourceSets in build.gradle like so:

```
sourceSets
{
    NiceFlav.res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/CLIENT_GROUP_1/res', 'src/NiceFlav/res']
}
```

hoping that resources in CLIENT_GROUP_1 would override resources in main, where they exist, and finally any resources that may or may not exist in NiceFlav would override anything in main or CLIENT_GROUP_1. But unfortunately when it comes to building, gradle just spits out errors about any resource that is duplicated in either CLIENT_GROUP_1 and/or NiceFlav.

How can I configure gradle so that the resources are combined in the required way?

(edit)
Using dimensions, at least in the default suggested configuration, doesn't work; if I create multiple dimensions I end up with directory structures like so:

```
src/Main
src/NiceFlavor
src/NiceFlavorCLIENT_GROUP_1
src/NiceFlavorCLIENT_GROUP_2
src/OtherFlavor
src/OtherFlavorCLIENT_GROUP_1 
src/OtherFlavorCLIENT_GROUP_2
...
```

and I would need to put all resources for CLIENT_GROUP_1 and CLIENT_GROUP_2 in every variant folder

What I really need is a directory structure which would look like this:

```
src/Main
src/CLIENT_GROUP_1
src/CILENT_GROUP_2
src/NiceFlavor
src/OtherFlavor
...
```

The build needs to then take all resources from Main, override any resources found  in CLIENT_GROUP_1 or CLIENT_GROUP_2 (depending on which group the flavour belongs to) and then finally override any resources found in the individual flavour directory.

side note, a flavor will only ever belong to one CLIENT_GROUP, so there is no need for multiple build variants for each flavor, other than the standard debug/release.

Comment: Hi LairdPleng. We're facing the same issue here. It seems like there's no way around having a complete copy of all resources in each sub flavour. Did you manage to find a work around?

Comment: @Schm1 No, I wasn't able to find a workaround, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can solve this by using `dimensions`

Here is an article on that topic:
https://proandroiddev.com/advanced-android-flavors-part-2-enter-flavor-dimensions-4ad7f486f6

> As example:
>
> client1Dev
>
> client1Staging
>
> client1Production
>
> client2Dev
>
> client2Staging
>
> client2Production

Here the longer introduction on developers web: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants

hope this helps

Comment: Hi there. Dimensions don't help here. See updated question for reasons why.